# Fix kitchen sink leak / seal?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

Kitchen sink leaks when there’s heavy water flow (Eg from the dishwasher). The water level seems to rise in the pipe and then it overflows where the pipe coming from the sink meets the pipe coming out of the trap. This part doesn’t seem to be sealed. Top pipe is 1.5 Should it?

What’s the best way to stop this leak?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check that your tapered washer is facing the right direction.  The flat side should be against the back of the plastic nut.